# change custom button action in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have the code that adds two custom buttons into grocerycrud:

```
    try{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_table('my_table_1')->set_subject('something');
        $crud->add_action('food 1', 'http://taimapedia.org/images/e/e6/Nom_icon_64.png', '','ui-icon-image',array($this,'get_row_id' ));
        $crud->add_action('pillow', 'http://www.ademi.com/movilidad/Imagenes/ico_medica.png', '','ui-icon-image',array($this,'get_row_id'));
        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_output_l($output);        
    }catch(Exception $e){
        show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
    }
```

then a function to return primary key depending the row I am

```
function get_row_id($primary_key , $row)
{
    return site_url('person/other/').'?id_person='.$row->id_person;
}
```

I want to pass the address `$which_url` the user should be redirected as well as  a parameter, but it did not work:

```
 function get_row_id($primary_key , $row, $which_url)
    {
        return site_url('person/'.$which_url.').'?id_person='.$row->id_person;
    }
```

how could I add this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be a typo?

Try:

```
function get_row_id($primary_key, $row, $which_url)
{
    return site_url('person/' . $which_url) . '?id_person=' . $row->id_person;
}
```

Comment: what about calling it `array($this,'get_row_id','adress_one')` ? becasue I get:

` A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func(Array) [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback

Filename: libraries/grocery_crud.php

Line Number: 1611`

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
$crud->add_action('action1', 'http://taimapedia.org/images/e/e6/Nom_icon_64.png', 'person/address_one');
$crud->add_action('action2', 'http://www.ademi.com/movilidad/Imagenes/ico_medica.png', 'person/address_two');
```